# Problem with sorting an array on specific column

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting

Problem sorting an array on a specific column.

```
[PSObject[]]$arr = @()

$arr += [PSObject]@{
    who = 'z';
    what = 'snake';
    where = 'c1';
    when = 'd1'
}
$arr += [PSObject]@{
    who = 'z';
    what = 'beer';
    where = 'c1';
    when = 'd1'
}
$arr += [PSObject]@{
    who = 'a';
    what = 'snake';
    where = 'c1';
    when = 'd1'
}
$arr += [PSObject]@{
    who = 'b';
    what = 'ape';
    where = 'c1';
    when = 'd1'
}

$arr | Sort-Object what
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
where                          c1
who                            a
when                           d1
what                           snake
where                          c1
who                            b
when                           d1
what                           ape
where                          c1
who                            z
when                           d1
what                           snake
where                          c1
who                            z
when                           d1
what                           beer
```

Thus not sorted on 'what'.

Any idea, please?

Comment: please wrap your code up with ``

Answer (score 0):

Casting hashtables to `[PSObject]` doesn't do what you expect. `PSObject` is already the base type of the hashtables you're defining, so your code merely creates a list of hashtables rather than creating a list of custom objects. To create custom objects from hashtables use the `PSCustomObject` type accelerator instead (requires PowerShell v3 or newer, on older versions use the `New-Object` cmdlet).

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $ht = @{'a'='b'; 'c'='d'}
PS C:\> $ht.GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Hashtable
PS C:\> $ht.PSBase.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.PSObject
PS C:\> $ht

Name                           Value
----                           -----
c                              d
a                              b

PS C:\> $o1 = [PSObject]$ht
PS C:\> $o1.GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Hashtable
PS C:\> $o1.PSBase.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.PSObject
PS C:\> $o1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
c                              d
a                              b

PS C:\> $o2 = [PSCustomObject]$ht
PS C:\> $o2.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
PS C:\> $o2.PSBase.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.PSObject
PS C:\> $o2

c a
- -
d b
```